# Browser sizing Ctrl +/- :: How to manipulate settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Explanation: In all browsers we are able to re-size the content with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>-</kbd> (in Windows) don't know about macs.

My site is built with CSS on a fluid layout, however I find that for my design the content looks best at 2 (times)  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>+</kbd>

**Question: How can I force the browser to display my page at 2 * Ctrl + as the default zoom view?
I prefer a CSS only method if available, if not I guess the next choice is JavaScript.**

Thanks!

Comment: If you built your site in `em`s, set `font-size: 2em` or something on `<body>` until it looks right. Otherwise... wrong approach.

Comment: I think the downvotes mean that this is a really bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never interfere with the user's display preferences. If your site is "best viewed at a certain zoom level", then you really should re-evaluate just how you're putting a site together.

For instance, just take all the measurements, lengths, sizes etc. and multiply them by 1.2